# Why can't I install Windows (7/8 or even 10) on hard disk but had linux before?

Tags: linux, windows, installation, bios

I used to have Windows 8.1 on my notebook, but i formatted and installed linux on it. Tried various distros. Everything always went well. Now i want to re-install Windows to make dual boot on it. I deleted all partitions using GParted and created only one NTFS. Tried Windows 8.1, 10 and 7 and the same problem always happens. Instead on going to normal setup, opens up a command window x:\window\system\cmd.exe. Keyboard doesn't work on it, seems all keys are function keys. Read somewhere, that i can do ESC during setup, and overlaps that window, the setup continues ok, but when stops asking some information to write, the keyboard doesn't work. Every linux distro i install, it's ok. What could it be happening with my notebook ?

Comment: Do you have a licensed Windows installation? Since you've formatted the disk, even after installation, you may have issues.

Comment: The single partition is your problem.  You should delete all your partition, then allow the Windows installer, to create the required partitions.

Comment: If you're installing in UEFI mode (as from factory) the drive needs to be GPT and better *not* to have any partition on it, only unused space. Windows needs to create the EFI partition and it can't because you likely used all the space for that single ntfs partition.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue many times until I found the perfect system. First thing to note is the cause for this issue. Linux uses a different file system when You install it, such as ext4.

What I do is I have a copy of ubcd.  (Ultimate boot cd). It is free and you can download it from the internet to burn to CD or USB.

You go into partition manager and use drive nuke. What that does is wipe everything from your drive completely. Would be as if you just got the drive off of the shelf. Now keep in mind this nuke will take a couple hours depending on how big the drive is.

Once it is done you can now reinstall windows on the machine.

Comment: Sounds like an overkill. I hope there is a more subtle way.

Comment: There very well might be. But when I had this issue a few years ago that's the answer that I found. For me it works like a charm. Because it's usually on a computer that I dont use daily so letting it sit for a couple hours is okay. Now the way to avoid this issue in the future when installing linux on a machine that had windows before is to do a dual boot so you can have both OS on same machine.

Comment: @Bill Understanding how this works will give a very different perspective. I agree with Kamil, it's overkill. Unless you need to wipe out sensitive information forcing an unneeded write cycle just wear the drive and wastes time for no good reason. Knowing what needs to be done to the drive to prepare it for the OS installation according to the installation method - often not much - saves time and complications.

Comment: I was just giving my experience. In my opinion it is easier for me to just do this because I can leave the computer and come back to it when it's done and know that when I install windows it will work fine. Also I have never had a drive fail or life of the drive shorten by doing this method. There are other ways to accomplish the same task.                                Another way to accomplish this is by shrinking the partition that linux is installed on and then removing the linux boot loader and installing windows boot loader. Then you can install windows on the system as well as linux